# SQL Command not properly ended in update statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Have 2 tables, `INVN_SBS` and `INVC_ITEM`.
Looking to set the one field in the table to `active = '0'` based on criteria of if `INVN_SBS.ITEM_SID` and `INVNSBS.ITEM` match and `INVN_SBS.DCS_CODE = 'SMP'`

So far i have:

```
UPDATE INVN_SBS 
SET ACTIVE='0' 
FROM 
   INVN_SBS,
   INVC_ITEM 
WHERE 
       INVN_SBS.ITEM_SID = INVC_ITEM.ITEM_SID
   and INVN_SBS.DCS_CODE='SMP'
```

However when run I get:

> ORA-00933:SQL Command not properly ended.

Am able to run a select statement to show me the item that match my criteria but the update is giving trouble.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support the `from` clause in an `update`.  Either use `merge` or a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution:

```
UPDATE INVN_SBS 
SET ACTIVE='0' 
where
  DCS_CODE='SMP' and
  ITEM_SID in (
    select ITEM_SID
    from INVC_ITEM
  )
```

If your primary keys support it, this should also work:

```
UPDATE (
  select INVN_SBS.ACTIVE
  FROM 
    INVN_SBS,
    INVC_ITEM 
  WHERE 
    INVN_SBS.ITEM_SID = INVC_ITEM.ITEM_SID
    and INVN_SBS.DCS_CODE='SMP'
)
SET ACTIVE='0'
```

If your primary keys aren't supportive of this second approach, it will let you know at compile-time.